# SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer cannot open "ipod-library" path in iOS13

Tags: ios, ios13, superpowered

SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer cannot open "ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=PERSISTANT_ID".

Was this path prohibited?
I'm having trouble playing Music.app songs.

There was no problem with iOS12.
Can't play with this path from iOS13.

macOS 10.15 Beta（19A546d）
iOS 13.1(17A5821e)

```c
player = new SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer(NULL, NULL, 44100, 0);
player->open([[NSURL URLWithString:@"ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id= PERSISTANT_ID"] fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on iOS 13.0 GM. An interesting observation is .mp3 files work but .m4a files do not.

Answer (score 0):

from superpowered support.

> we will investigate this when iOS 13 will have an official release.
>   iOS betas have many features turned off and on from version to
>   version.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming Superpowered release will be compatible with this feature of iOS 13. Expect it in a few days.

Comment: I applied the new version(2.0) and confirmed that the music can play "ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=PERSISTANT_ID".
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**upgrade Superpowered 2.0**

・fix to namespace Superpowered

・missing link OpenSource

SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO.h/m,SuperpoweredNBandEQ.h/cpp

・StereoMixer

process()

Levels -> Gain

・SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent -> PlayerEvent

**problem**

SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_EOF is missing.

Perhaps AdvancedAudioPlayer::eofRecently() instead.